# Does the Magento search form have CSRF vulnerabilities?

Tags: php, magento, csrf

I have run two different PCI scans against a Magento website, and both find "possible CSRF vulnerabilities" on certain pages.

The only form on any of the pages is the search form. I can't figure out how that form would open a vulnerability on the Magento site.  Is there something to be fixed here?  Or do I just need to ignore what these PCI scans are telling me?  We are just using the stock search forms.

Comment: Doesn’t `/catalogsearch/result/` output the search string? Does the scan give you a dangerous string that succeeded so that you can try it yourself?

Comment: The scan says it "did not exploit the flaw".  And it says "You will have to audit the source of the CGI scripts and check if they are actually affected."  Which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: it could just be inputing a string on any form it finds and then searching the resulting page for the same string in order to check for the possibility of CSRF. I think in the case of search, since Magento outputs the search term by default, it is probably scrubbing the string to make it safe.